# Is it possible to "unpack" a dict in one call?

Tags: python, dictionary, unpack

I was looking for a way to "unpack" a dictionary in a generic way and found [a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897623/unpacking-a-passed-dictionary-into-the-functions-name-space-in-python) (and answers) which explained various techniques (TL;DR: it is not too elegant).

That question, however, addresses the case where the keys of the dict are not known, the OP anted to have them added to the local namespace automatically.

My problem is possibly simpler: I get a dict from a function and would like to dissecate it on the fly, knowing the keys I will need (I may not need all of them every time). Right now I can only do

```
def myfunc():
    return {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

x = myfunc()
a = x['a']
my_b_so_that_the_name_differs_from_the_key = x['b']
# I do not need c this time
```

while I was looking for the equivalent of

```
def myotherfunc():
    return 1, 2

a, b = myotherfunc()
```

but for a dict (which is what is returned by my function). I do not want to use the latter solution for several reasons, one of them being that it is not obvious which variable corresponds to which returned element (the first solution has at least the merit of being readable).

Is such operation available?

Comment: `a, b = foo().get('a'), foo().get('b')` I suppose could work. The problem with  unpacking it in the usual way is the unordered nature of dicts.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to call the function twice (or more), otherwise I would have gone for the (first) solution mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really must, you can use an [`operator.itemgetter()` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to extract values for multiple keys as a tuple:

```
from operator import itemgetter

a, b = itemgetter('a', 'b')(myfunc())
```

This is still not pretty; I'd prefer the explicit and *readable* separate lines where you first assign the return value, *then* extract those values.

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> def myfunc():
...     return {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
... 
>>> itemgetter('a', 'b')(myfunc())
(1, 2)
>>> a, b = itemgetter('a', 'b')(myfunc())
>>> a
1
>>> b
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use map:

```
def myfunc():
    return {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

a,b = map(myfunc().get,["a","b"])
print(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `operator.itemgetter()` method, you can also write your own `myotherfunc()`. It takes list of the required keys as an argument and returns a tuple of their corresponding value.

```
def myotherfunc(keys_list):
    reference_dict = myfunc()
    return tuple(reference_dict[key] for key in keys_list)

>>> a,b = myotherfunc(['a','b'])
>>> a
1
>>> b
2

>>> a,c = myotherfunc(['a','c'])
>>> a
1
>>> c
3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're from javascript world you may miss this kind of syntax:

```
const {a, b} = d
```

Here's a dirty way to have that in python:

```py
import traceback

def auto_unpack(d: dict):
    stack = traceback.extract_stack()
    for frame_summary in stack:
        if 'auto_unpack' in frame_summary.line:
            lhs = frame_summary.line.split('=')[0].strip()
            if lhs[0] == '[':
                assert lhs[-1] == ']'
                lhs = lhs[1:-1]
            if lhs[0] == '(':
                assert lhs[-1] == ')'
                lhs = lhs[1:-1]
            keys = [s.strip() for s in lhs.split(',') if s]
            return [d[key] for key in keys]


d = {
    'a': 4,
    'b': 5,
}
a, b = auto_unpack(d)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Prints:

```
4
5
```

But use this is basically a hack, so only use it for your fun little scripts. I recommend not to use this in big projects as it will confuse co-workers, potentially cause new bugs, and generally adds complexity to the code.

Also, the above code simply fails when the assignment is multi-line, e.g.:

```py
(
  a,
  b
) = auto_unpack(d)
```

The following code takes a similar approach but at a lower level, which is less prone to formatting issues but it relies on low-level conventions which are not a part of the python language specs. Anyways, here's the code:

```
import inspect
import opcode

def auto_unpack(d: dict):
    keys = []
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    i = frame.f_lasti
    code = frame.f_code
    visiter_store_before = False
    while i < len(code.co_code):
        instr = code.co_code[i]
        arg = code.co_code[i+1]
        if instr == opcode.opmap['STORE_FAST']:
            keys.append(code.co_varnames[arg])
            visiter_store_before = True
        elif instr == opcode.opmap['STORE_NAME']:
            keys.append(code.co_names[arg])
            visiter_store_before = True
        elif visiter_store_before:
            break
        i += 2
    return [d[key] for key in keys]
```

The code above works on Python 3.6+. For python < 3.6 you should update it use variable size steps based on [HAVE_ARGUMENT](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-HAVE_ARGUMENT) criteria. This code too is not recommended for serious use for the same reasons stated above.

Also here's the opposite, auto-pack:

```py
def auto_pack(*items):
    result = {}
    frame = inspect.currentframe().f_back
    i = frame.f_lasti
    code = frame.f_code
    while i > 0:
        instr = code.co_code[i]
        arg = code.co_code[i+1]
        if instr == opcode.opmap['LOAD_FAST']:
            name = code.co_varnames[arg]
            if name == 'auto_pack':
                break
            result[name] = code.co_varnames[arg]
        elif instr == opcode.opmap['LOAD_NAME']:
            name = code.co_names[arg]
            if name == 'auto_pack':
                break
            result[name] = frame.f_locals[name]
        i -= 2
    return result


a = 5
b = 7
c = 8
d = auto_pack(a, b, c)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{'c': 8, 'b': 7, 'a': 5}
```