# Python double asterisk that is not **kwargs but rather gets used on the function call itself

Tags: python, python-3.x

was watching here:

https://youtu.be/F5mRW0jo-U4?t=9267

he proceeds to write the call:

```
Product.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
```

Can someone explain what is the difference between

```
Product.objects.create(my_form.cleaned_data)
```

and

Product.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["unpacking" a passed dictionary into the function's name space in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897623/unpacking-a-passed-dictionary-into-the-functions-name-space-in-python)

Comment: It basically unpacks a mapping-like object into named arguments calls... so eg: `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` - calling `f(**d)` is equivalent to calling `f(a=1, b=2, c=3)`...

Comment: @JonClements thanks jon, feel free to add an answer

Comment: @Toskan no need... I know this has been explained thoroughly with some decent examples in another post... (just struggling to find the one I have in mind though...)

Comment: yeah, right, you cannot find it? I couldnt find it either. And I'm sure, many other python beginners cannot find it. But hey, who cares

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that `my_form.cleaned_data` is a dict, or some other kind of mapping, then `create(**my_form.cleaned_data)` will pass all the dict's entries as keyword arguments. So:

```py
def my_fun(a=None, b=None):
    print(a)
    print(b)

my_dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}

my_fun(**my_dict)
```

would print:

```
1
2
```