# Using Dictionary values as function parameters?

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

I'm simulating a dictionary of fictional stocks by merging different lists:

```
inipri = []
riskfree = []
strike = []
optnr = []

for x in range(10000):
    inipri.append(np.random.uniform(50 , 100))
    riskfree.append(np.random.uniform(0 , 0.1))
    strike.append(np.random.uniform(inipri[x] , inipri[x] + 25))
    optnr.append("Option" + str(x + 1))

OptDict = dict(zip(optnr , zip(inipri , riskfree , strike)))
```

This creates 10000 stocks with the following layout, so the stock number followed by 3 parameters.

```
OptDict[1] 
(54.867520983134476, 0.09902524143504071, 59.64631412799602)
```

I have generated a function which requires three imputs, corresponding to the values for each dictionary key.

The function is defined as the following (The computations aren't relevant):

```
def option_tree(S0 , r , K , sigma = 0.182575441 , N = 2 , T = 2 , array_out=False):
```

How do i pair these dict values to the function? I've tried to test a single stock by typing:

```
option_tree(OptDict[1])
```

Which yields:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
in 
 ----> 1 option_tree(OptDict[1])

TypeError: option_tree() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'r' and 'K'
```

As seen above my dictionary has 3 values, one for S0 , r and K?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55689529/python-double-asterisk-that-is-not-kwargs-but-rather-gets-used-on-the-function is of interest

Comment: `option_tree()` is defined to require three arguments, and you're only passing one.

Comment: Hi, Try `OptDict[1][index] `. Index `0,1,2` will give you `(54.867520983134476, 0.09902524143504071, 59.64631412799602)` based on the index given in `OptDict[1][index]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `*` operator that will unpack your tuple and pass it to the function:

```
option_tree(*OptDict[1])
```

You can take a look at this [source](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/) that splendidly explains asterisks in python.